# Webscraping table data using python

Tags: python, web-scraping

Objective: 
Using Python, I want to webscrape last 30 days average value from "https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=USD&To=INR" (HTML element as inspected on Chrome browser is "76.2664").

Disclaimer: I am only scraping the value for educational purpose

I can clearly see the above element in the Chrome browser but can't read using BeautifulSoup rendering engine.

Below is the code, I have created so far:

```
import requests, bs4
res = requests.get('https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=USD&To=INR')
res.raise_for_status()
exampleSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
elems = exampleSoup.select('div')
print(elems)
```

Questions:
1. Why are the elements visible on Chrome but not in HTML Source code? 
2. Am I using the right rendering engine (beautifulsoup) for my purpose? 
3. What is the CSS selector should I use to get the last 30 days average value?

Comment: Regardless of whether you're doing it for educational purposes, this site and many others are specifically designed to prevent exactly what you're trying to do. That being said, I would suggest using `selenium` or `chromedriver` instead of `bs4`.

Comment: I appreciate your time to answer my question and I will try using them.

Comment: If you can't see elements in your source code, that's probably because those elements are being rendered using javascript, to be able to scrape that you'll probably need scrapy-splash library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see in the network tab it comes from this endpoint

```
https://www.xe.com/api/stats.php?fromCurrency=USD&toCurrency=INR
```

under

```
json['payload']['Last_30_Days']['average']
```

It explicitly states automated extraction is against terms of use.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am dropping the plans to extract from XE.com and trying to look for a public information.

Comment: No worries. Please remember to consider accepting if answered. You don't have to but it is helpful.